# How to get current user jwt token?

Tags: 8, users, authentication-authorization

In a custom module, I need to get the jwt token (access_token) related to the current user. Following this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/jwt/issues/2957273) I've tried to get it, but without success, because get_jwt_key() and jwt_token_params() are not defined and I can't find where they are defined:

```
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
...    
public function getAccessToken() {
  $uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
  // Add JWT access_token
  $key = get_jwt_key(); //key for generate jwt token
  $token = jwt_token_params($uid); // parameters to be added in token.
  $access_token = JWT::encode($token, $key);
  return $access_token;
}
```

I've tried only with:

```
$access_token = $this->jwtAuth->generateToken();
```

But I haven't found how to initialize $jwtAuth service to generate the token.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code shown on comment [#2](https://www.drupal.org/project/jwt/issues/2957273#comment-12658702) in [Get the token bearer with the JWT module after log in rest method](https://www.drupal.org/project/jwt/issues/2957273) is the code for an event subscriber class. What that comment doesn't show is the definition of the event subscriber service.

As described in [Subscribe to and dispatch events / Drupal 8 Events](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/subscribe-to-and-dispatch-events#s-drupal-8-events), the .services.yml file should contain lines similar to the following ones. (Replace *YOURMODULE* with the module machine name, and *YOURCLASS* with the class name.)

```yaml
services:
  YOURMODULE_YOURCLASS:
    class: '\Drupal\YOURMODULE\Listener\YOURCLASS'
    tags:
      - { name: 'event_subscriber' }
    arguments:
      - '@path.current'
      - '@jwt.authentication.jwt'
```

Contrary to what the comment says, the file containing the `\Drupal\YOURMODULE\Listener\YOURCLASS` class isn't the *src/Listener/yourfile.php* file, but the *src/Listener/YOURCLASS.php* file contained in the module directory.

As side notes:

- As described in [Events](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/events/8.9.x), the file containing an event subscriber class isn't required to be in a specific directory. Drupal core modules normally put those files in the *EventSubscriber* directory.
- The *JSON Web Token Authentication (JWT)* module doesn't define neither `get_jwt_key()` nor `jwt_token_params()`. The comment doesn't show the code for those functions, but they need to be implemented from the module. (In that case, their names should be prefixed by the module machine name.)
  -The `YOURCLASS` class shown in that comment initializes `$this->jwtAuth` in its constructor, but `onHttpLoginResponse()` doesn't even use it.

  ```php
  /**
   * Add JWT access token to user login API response
   */
  public function onHttpLoginResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
    // Halt if not user login request
    if ($this->currentPath->getPath() !== '/user/login') {
      return;
    }
    // Get response
    $response = $event->getResponse();
    // Ensure not error response
    if ($response->getStatusCode() !== 200) {
      return;
    }
    // Get request
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    // Just handle JSON format for now
    if ($request->query->get('_format') !== 'json') {
      return;
    }
    // Decode and add JWT token
    if ($content = $response->getContent()) {
      if ($decoded = Json::decode($content)) {
        $uid = $decoded['current_user']['uid'];
        // Add JWT access_token
        $key = get_jwt_key(); //key for generate jwt token
        $token = jwt_token_params($uid); // parameters to be added in token.
        $access_token = JWT::encode($token, $key);
        $decoded['jwt_access_token'] = $access_token;
        // Set new response JSON
        $response->setContent(Json::encode($decoded));
        $event->setResponse($response);
      }
    }
  }
  ```

  Clearly, the code shown in that comment is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After reading and some test I did it with this: $jwt = \Drupal::service('jwt.authentication.jwt');  $access_token = $jwt->generateToken();